# Solr not working on DSpace installation

Tags: java, jsp, solr, dspace

I am getting the following error page (see bottom) when trying to log into:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/
```

So far, I've tried the following to no success:

1. Restarting Tomcat (countless times)
2. Running DSpace's commands (`stats-log-converter` & `stats-log-importer`)
3. Copying everything (SQL and files) from the original install to a fresh one.

A little bit of history:

The main symptom is that we cannot get the statistics up and running. The page for statistics returns nothing but a blank page. Trying to fix that I stumbled into this, which I suspect is the culprit.

This is the error: (image attached as well)

```
    HTTP Status 500 -

    type Exception report

    message

    description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

    An error occurred at line: 32 in the jsp file: /admin/index.jsp
    The method getRequestHandlers() in the type SolrCore is not applicable for the arguments (Class<ReplicationHandler>)
    29: <%-- jsp:include page="header.jsp"/ --%>
    30: <%-- do a verbatim include so we can use the local vars --%>
    31: <%@include file="header.jsp" %>
    32: <%boolean replicationhandler = !core.getRequestHandlers(ReplicationHandler.class).isEmpty();%>
    33: <br clear="all">
    34: <table>
    35: 


    Stacktrace:
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
        org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:589)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:295)
        org.dspace.solr.filters.LocalHostRestrictionFilter.doFilter(LocalHostRestrictionFilter.java:60)
    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.26 logs.

    Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
```

[image: SOLR error]

Comment: Which Dspace version are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like version mismatch or version compatibility issue with jar files.

Try running fresh install after clean up. Make sure you have all Jars at `/WEB-INF/lib` in the Solr module.

Reference:  http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.dspace.user/15055